# How to use "CASE WHEN" on select join magento 2

Tags: magento2, join

I try to get shipping postcode, shipping city, billing postcode, billing city of order, join to table sales_order_address, but i can't use "CASE WHEN" on Join. Can someone help me, please.

This is my code,

```
$a = new \Zend_Db_Expr('CASE WHEN sales_order_address.address_type <> "shipping" THEN street END');
$b = 'CASE WHEN sales_order_address.address_type <> "shipping" THEN postcode END';
$c = 'CASE WHEN sales_order_address.address_type <> "shipping" THEN city END';
$d = 'CASE WHEN sales_order_address.address_type <> "billing" THEN street END';
$e = 'CASE WHEN sales_order_address.address_type <> "billing" THEN postcode END';
$f = 'CASE WHEN sales_order_address.address_type <> "billing" THEN city END';

$this->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            $joinTable . ' as cgf',
            'main_table.entity_id = cgf.order_id',
            ['invoices' => 'cgf.increment_id']
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            'sales_order_address', 
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_address.parent_id',
            array(
                'country_id' => 'country_id', 
                'shipping_street' => $a,  
                'shipping_postcode' => $b, 
                'shipping_city' => $c, 
                'billing_street' => $d, 
                'billing_postcode' => $e, 
                'billing_city' => $f
            )
        )
->where('main_table.store_id = ' . $storeId);
```

Echo select, it show

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `cgf`.`increment_id` AS `invoices`, `sales_order_address`.`country_id`, `CASE WHEN sales_order_address`.`address_type <> "shipping" THEN street END`, `CASE WHEN sales_order_address`.`address_type <> "shipping" THEN postcode END` AS `shipping_postcode`, `CASE WHEN sales_order_address`.`address_type <> "shipping" THEN city END` AS `shipping_city`, `CASE WHEN sales_order_address`.`address_type <> "billing" THEN street END` AS `billing_street`, `CASE WHEN sales_order_address`.`address_type <> "billing" THEN postcode END` AS `billing_postcode`, `CASE WHEN sales_order_address`.`address_type <> "billing" THEN city END` AS `billing_city` FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_invoice_grid` AS `cgf` ON main_table.entity_id = cgf.order_id LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order_address.parent_id WHERE (main_table.store_id = 2)
```

You can see there error, there shouldn't have ` before CASE and after END

```
`CASE WHEN sales_order_address`.`address_type <> "billing" THEN postcode END`
```

Please help me, or welcome for another way